# ScrollView is not working correctly with GeometryReader

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scrollview, geometryreader

I have some issues with the scrollview and GeometryReader. I want to have a list of items under an image. And each item should have the following width and height:
 `((width of the entire screen - leading padding - trailing padding) / 2)`.  
I have tried two approaches for my use case. This is the code structure of my first one:

## Approach #1

```
ScrollView
   - VStack
      - Image
      - GeometryReader
         - ForEach
            - Text
```

I am using the geometry reader to get the width of the VStack as it has a padding and I don't want to have the full width of the scrollview.

But with the GeometryReader, only the last item from the ForEach loop is shown on the UI. And the GeometryReader has only a small height. See screenshot.

#### Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var value: String
}

struct ContentView: View {

    func items() -> [Item] {
        var items = [Item]()
        for i in 0..<100 {
            items.append(Item(value: "Item #\(i)"))
        }
        return items
    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.green)

                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    ForEach(self.items()) { item in
                        Text(item.value)
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width / CGFloat(2), height: geometry.size.width / CGFloat(2))
                            .background(Color.red)
                    }
                }
                .background(Color.blue)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The red color are the items in the ForEach loop. Blue the GeometryReader and green just the image.

[image: Screenshot]

## Approach #2

```
ScrollView
   -GeometryReader
      - VStack
         - Image
         - ForEach
            -Text
```

Then the items in my ForEach loop are rendered correctly but it's not possible to scroll anymore.

#### Code

```
import SwiftUI

struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var value: String
}

struct ContentView: View {

    func items() -> [Item] {
        var items = [Item]()
        for i in 0..<100 {
            items.append(Item(value: "Item #\(i)"))
        }
        return items
    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                        .padding()
                        .foregroundColor(.green)

                    ForEach(self.items()) { item in
                        Text(item.value)
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width / CGFloat(2), height: geometry.size.width / CGFloat(2))
                            .background(Color.red)
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image: screenshotNo2]

How can I archive to have the UI correctly shown. Am I'm missing something here?

I would really appreciate some help.
Thank you.

### **EDIT**

I found a workaround to have the UI correctly rendered with a working scrollView but that looks quite hacky to me. 
I am using a PreferenceKey for this workaround. 


I am using the geometryReader inside the scrollview with a height of 0. Only to get the width of my VStack. 
On preferenceKeyChange I am updating a state variable and using this for my item to set the width and height of it.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var value: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var width: CGFloat = 0

    func items() -> [Item] {
        var items = [Item]()
        for i in 0..<100 {
            items.append(Item(value: "Item #\(i)"))
        }
        return items
    }

    struct WidthPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
        typealias Value = [CGFloat]

        static var defaultValue: [CGFloat] = [0]

        static func reduce(value: inout [CGFloat], nextValue: () -> [CGFloat]) {
            value.append(contentsOf: nextValue())
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.green)

                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    VStack {
                        EmptyView()

                    }.preference(key: WidthPreferenceKey.self, value: [geometry.size.width])
                }
                .frame(height: 0)

                ForEach(self.items()) { item in
                    Text(item.value)
                        .frame(width: self.width / CGFloat(2), height: self.width / CGFloat(2))
                        .background(Color.red)
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .onPreferenceChange(WidthPreferenceKey.self) { value in
            self.width = value[0]
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Is this the only way of doing that, or is there a more elegant and easier way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, since you are using a VStack, means you need a vertical scrolling. So, you need to set maxHeight property, instead of maxWidth.

In your first approach, you are wrapping your for..loop in a GeometryReader before wrapping it in a VStack. So, SwiftUI doesn't recognize that you want those items in a vertical stack until before building GeometryReader and its children. So, a good workaround is to put GeometryReader as the very first block before your scrollView to make it work:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var value: String
}

struct ContentView: View {

    func items() -> [Item] {
        var items = [Item]()
        for i in 0..<100 {
            items.append(Item(value: "Item #\(i)"))
        }
        return items
    }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
        ScrollView {
            VStack {

                Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.green)

                    ForEach(self.items()) { item in
                        Text(item.value)
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width / CGFloat(2), height: geometry.size.width / CGFloat(2))
                            .background(Color.red)
                    }
            }
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
            .padding()
        }
        }
        .background(Color.blue)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The issue with your second approach, is that you are wrapping your infinite-height VStack in a GeometryReader, which is not necessarily has an infinite height. Besides, GeometryReader is a SwiftUI block to read the dimensions from outer block, rather than getting dimensions from its children.

Generally speaking, if you want to use Geometry of current main SwiftUI component which you are making (or the device screen, if it's a fullscreen component), then put GeometryReader at a parent level of other components. Otherwise, you need to put the GeometryReader component as the unique child of a well-defined dimensions SwiftUI block.

Edited: to add padding, simply add required padding to your scrollView:

```
ScrollView{
  //...
}
.padding([.leading,.trailing],geometry.size.width / 8)
```

or in just one direction:

```
ScrollView{
  //...
}
.padding(leading,geometry.size.width / 8) // or any other value, e.g. : 30
```

If you need padding just for items in for loop, simply put the for loop in another VStack and add above padding there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that in your case the geometryReaders size.width is equal to the width of the entire screen. But I need for the items in the for each loop (screen with - leading padding - trailing padding). Any Idea how to archive that?

Comment: @stefOCDP. Edited. Is that what you are looking for?