# GeometryReader inside a ScrollView collapses the GeometryReader, regardless of child sizes

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to make a sub view which contains a drawing which I want the size to be proportional to a fraction of the parent container.

This works fine except when put inside a scroll view somewhere up the hierarchy.

As seen from the screenshots when inside of the stack the loudest as expected. But when you put inside a scroll view the size of the geometry reader collapses to near zero and its children overflow its boundaries. As though it's rendering its children on a different Z index. In fact if you remove the wrapping VStack from the geometry render contents it doesn't fact layout all its children as though it were wrapped in a ZStack.

**EDIT:**
To be clear: the ScrollView is *not* owned by the component. The component should not be aware if it's in a ScrollView or not - it's just a poor helpless component, being thrown around. That's why I put the ScrollView into the preview code, not the component.

I've tried all sorts of combinations of fixed sizes and men and mags and ideal. The only work around I could find was this [hacky solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61603365/105741) - the edited part of the question near the bottom where the width reported by the geometry reader is captured through a workaround into a state variable and then re-used to set the frame size of a sibling view.

Note, I'm a complete beginner. There seems to be some interaction between the scroll view and the geometry reader that is beyond my current understanding.

Seems to be a [confusing topic](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswiftui%5D+title%3Ascrollview+title%3Ageometryreader).

```
import SwiftUI

struct ScrollViewGeoReader: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader{ g in
            VStack{
                let width = g.size.width
                Circle().frame(width: width/3, height: width/3, alignment: .center)
                Text("inside geo")
                Text("inside geo")
                Text("inside geo \(width)")
                Text("inside geo")
                Text("inside geo")
            }
            .border(Color.green, width: 2)
        }
        .border(Color.red, width: 3)
    }
}

struct ScrollViewGeoReader_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        VStack {
//            VStack {
            ScrollView {
                ScrollViewGeoReader()
                Text("Next scrollview item")
            }
            .border(Color.blue, width: 2)

        }
    }
}
```

ZStack (expected layout):

[image: ZStack (expected layout)]

ScrollView (see how the red frame of the geometry read it has collapsed to size 10):

[image]

### EDIT:

Also note that the same problem occurs with or without the circle, which is also a problem I have. So it's not chicken / egg as far as the width capturing is concerned, at least in terms of Circles. I would have though the Text components know their own size, and would tell the GR.

[image]

vs

[image]

Comment: ScrollView has no own size and GeometryReader has no own size, so you've got into chicken-egg problem, ie. no-one knows size to render, so collapsed. You must have definite frame size for items inside ScrollView.

Comment: Most probably you just need to place GeometryReader outsize ScrollView to give width/3 size for Circle and everything else will be ok.

Comment: Thanks. Can’t rearrange order because the child view doesn’t know if it’ll be in a scroll view or not. 

Ok forget the circle. But the Text events specify a size, but I see the same thing happen. (Ie remove the circle and the layout is still busted).

Comment: So why isn't Text enough to tell GR it's size?

Comment: GR takes free size of parent, not children. Reread my first comment.

Comment: @AntonyStubbs did you figure out a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is scratchy (w/o subviews separation) possible solution for layout. If/when internal subviews separated the geometry width can be injected by constructor arguments.

Tested with Xcode 12.

[image: demo]

```
struct TestScrollViewWithGeometry: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader{ g in
            ScrollView {
                VStack{
                    let width = g.size.width
                    Circle().frame(width: width/3, height: width/3, alignment: .center)
                    Text("inside geo")
                    Text("inside geo")
                    Text("inside geo \(width)")
                    Text("inside geo")
                    Text("inside geo")
                }
                .border(Color.green, width: 2)
                Text("Next scrollview item")
            }
            .border(Color.blue, width: 2)
        }
        .border(Color.red, width: 3)
    }
}
```

Comment: You’ve changed the descendent ordering. Part of the requirement is that the view doesn’t know if it will be within a scroll view or not. Ie the scroll view could be several components up the tree. I should edit the question to clarify that I suppose.

Comment: I've updated the question. Pushing the GR higher up the tree, and passing the width down the tree (as you mentioned constructor args), would appear to be one solution but it's far from ideal as the view hierarchy gets deep. And if that is in fact the only solution, then the answer would appear to be that a component cannot use geometry reader to find its parents dimensions need a ScrollView is involved. Injection could help, but that's also smelly.

Comment: BTW, if you like, make a minor edit to your question and I'll upvote it. Maybe emphasise the constructor argh injection bit :)